# How to append a new line in a textbox when receiving data from an API in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to retrieve data from https://ip-api.com. I have requested multiple variables and would like to append each line of different data. I have a textbox and have requested multiple variables in the same link request.

Let me provide an example of what I have right now.

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string results = wc.DownloadString("http://ip-api.com/line/?fields=status,message,continent,continentCode,country,countryCode,region,regionName,city,district,zip,lat,lon,timezone,offset,currency,isp,org,as,asname,reverse,mobile,proxy,hosting,query");
textBox1.Text = results;
```

The output comes as this

```
successNorth AmericaNAUnited StatesUScensoredForPrivacy
```

I would prefer it look like this

```
success
North America
NA
United States
US
CensoredForPrivacy
```

How can I do this with the way I have provided or is there another way?

Comment: @David In the textbox it looks like this `successNorth AmericaNAUnited StatesUScensoredForPrivacy` but if you were to go to the same link I had provided and check it in a browser, it is organized like the second example I provided. Thats why I was wondering if it was something I had to specify or if I have to individually request each option.

Comment: @MarkusAnd Windows. I am building on Visual Studio 2022 and I am using .NET Framework WinForms. Not that it might matter.

Comment: Use a RichTextBox, it just needs `\n` as separator.

Comment: I should have made myself more clear. Obviously you use Windows since it is winforms but you are not running it through a virtual machine?

Comment: @Jimi Where would I put \n tho? Wouldn't that interupt the link?

Comment: @MarkusAnd No, I am not running on a virtual machine.

Comment: Put it? It's already in the string you get back. `\r\n` is Windows only, `\n` is the common ground (i.e., when you get strings from a service, you cannot expect lines of text separated by `\r\n`).

Comment: So where would \n go? If I put it in between the link such as `"http://ip-api.com/line/?fields=status,message \n continent,continentCode...` wouldn't that break the link?

Comment: You don't have to put anything anywhere. I suggested to replace the TextBox with a RichTextBox. See how it goes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WebClient` method `DownloadString` will append LF newline characters (\n) but a `TextBox` requires CRLF newline characters (\r\n).

This can be solved by splitting at `\n` then using `AppendText(Environment.NewLine)`

```
string results = wc.DownloadString("http://ip-api.com/line/?fields=status,message,continent,continentCode,country,countryCode,region,regionName,city,district,zip,lat,lon,timezone,offset,currency,isp,org,as,asname,reverse,mobile,proxy,hosting,query");
string[] headers = results.split("\n");
foreach(string s in headers) {
    textBox1.AppendText(s);
    textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: WebClient doesn't append anything. It returns what has been sent as a string using the Default encoding (if not otherwise specified).

Comment: Thank you for your help however I get an error at `("\n");`

The error says "Arguement 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char'"

Comment: @Jimi you are correct, append was perhaps a careless word choice.

Comment: @FrigginFragger try ('\n') or .Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());

Comment: Dude, thank you so much. Appreciate you guys greatly!